# webpack dev sever proxy issue(CORS)

Tags: javascript, webpack, proxy, cors, webpack-dev-server

I have CORS problem...

This is my webpack.config.js devServer config

```
devServer: {
port: 9000,
hot: true,
proxy: "https://www.youtube.com",
```

},

And this is the code

```
fetch("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ");
```

I think it should work but I got cors error...
What is the problem

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup the proxy in the following way:

```
devServer: {
        ...
        proxy: {
           '/watch': {
                target: 'http://localhost:9000',
                router: () => 'https://www.youtube.com',
                logLevel: 'debug' /*optional*/
           }
        }
}
```

and call the API for video as this:

```
fetch('/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ')
```